# How do I prevent mobile devices from automatically downloading a PDF on my website?

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf

So I've got a part on my website where I show a pdf in an iframe. 
This works perfectly fine on computers.
However, some mobile devices start downloading the pdf immediately when they load the website.

This is the code I use.

```
<div class="showbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="embed-container">
        <iframe src="/images/pdf-file.pdf" style="border:none;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

**So I just want the mobile users to be able to visit the website without automatically downloading the pdf.**

Any ideas how to pull this off?

Comment: You can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and look for mobile browsers user-agent http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/

Comment: The PDF file would only be displayed in browsers which can read PDF files. This isn't a mobile-specific issue.

Comment: Whats wrong with mobile phones showing PDF?

Answer (score 0):

how about you use Responsive utility classes ?

take a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

scroll down untill "Responsive utility classes"

Answer (score 0):

you can set your html like this:

```
<div class="showbox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="embed-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

and then put this js anywhere:

```
if( !/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('.showbox .embed-container').append('<iframe src="/images/pdf-file.pdf" style="border:none;"></iframe>');
}
```